# Google 2FA: I only received the first verification code, no further codes

Tags: google-account, multi-factor-auth

I've set up 2 step verification on my Google account using the SMS option. I received an initial verification code immediately, which I used to confirm turning it on. So far, everything worked perfectly.

However, when I tried to connect my devices, no further codes arrived, and the one I received earlier does not work anymore. This has been going for days, and other SMS arrive just fine. I finally used some of the backup codes I luckily printed to turn 2FA off again, as it is unusable like this.

Is this a known issue?

<sub>I found lots of people having trouble receiving the initial SMS, but none where only the very first one went through. I'm located in Germany using the Congstar D1 provider if that matters.</sub>